# Understanding $scope and in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I created this snippet using html5 geolocation api.
If the user allow and display the lat,lng with `{{lat}}`

I don't understand why the lat only display in second click.
I thought the showPosition() has already triggered?
You can see it show in console in the first click.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
{{lat}}
  <button ng-click="getLocation()">Click</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getLocation = function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
  function showPosition(position) {
    $scope.lat = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude;
    $scope.lng = "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    console.log($scope.lat);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post the code here instead of linking to an outside site. We need both the HTML and the JS.

Comment: Call `$scope.$apply()` at the bottom of `showPosition()`.  The callback is called "outside" of Angular, so you need to tell Angular to run a digest cycle.

Comment: Thank @MarkRajcok , I will check out the $apply.

Comment: @MarkRajcok actually gave an answer: `showPosition` is called async, so code inside of that function should be wrapped by `$scope.$apply(function() { ....})`

Comment: @ValentynShybanov, yeah, I didn't want to give out my coordinates :), so I wanted vzhen to test it before I wrote an actual answer.  (I'm always leery about posting an answer if I can't test a modified plunker/fiddle to see if it actually works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback function `showPosition` is called "outside" Angular, so although your `$scope` properties will be updated, the view will not update because Angular doesn't know about these changes.

Call `$scope.$apply()` at the bottom of function `showPosition()`.  This will cause a [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) to run, and Angular will notice the changes you made to the $scope (because of the $watches that Angular set up due to using {{}}s in your HTML) and update the view.